# iPhone USB wired hotspot tethering doesn't work on my Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, iphone, hot-spot, tethering

I don't know why but the USB wired hotspot doesn't work on my Ubuntu 18.04. On my Windows desktop it works and all iPhone settings are correctly adjusted. I already tried to install some packages using the following commands:

- `sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils`
- `sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-dev`
- `sudo apt-get install ipheth-utils`

I see a question mark on the upper right corner of the screen:

[image: right panel]

Hopefully someone knows how to solve this issue!

Comment: "*doesn't work*" - can you be more specific?  What exactly isn't working?  Do you mean to say that you cannot connect your Ubuntu device to a hotspot hosted by your phone? Or that you can't connect your phone to a hotspot you are trying to create in Ubuntu. Please describe your problem exactly how it manifests on your Ubuntu device.

Comment: Hello Nmath, sorry for the unclear explanation. The hotspot is already on the iPhone but my ubuntu kinda doesnt recognize the iPhone hotspot. There is no internet connection when i ping with 8.8.8.8. On the right upper corner, i see the question mark (see the picture in my previous post). This is all what i know

Comment: You can use the [edit] feature to add more details to your question.

Comment: We’re you able to resolve this issue?